# Generic comparator to sort Java Collections (List, Set)

Tags: java, generics, collections, comparator

I need some generic comparator which would accept instances of List or Set as an argument, and order direction argument (ASC, DESC), and then return the sorted collection. I can not seem to find on internet this example, and am in a horrible rush. I know I dont ask question in appropriate way, since I dont have any code to begin with but am in a horrible rush. Collections will contain objects which implement comparable and dates.

Any examples, implementations very much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I can understand you sorting a list but not a set.  Java does have a `SortedSet` but you don't actually sort them, they just present their items in sorted order when you iterate over them.  What exactly do you want this "comparator" to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Collections class has a `reverseOrder` method which returns a comparator for a generic type `T` which should satisfy your requirement for the DESC comparator. If you are passing your `Collection` to the `Collections.sort()` method, it automatically uses the ASC sort.

Also, "sorting" doesn't mean a lot when it comes to "sets" which maintain "unique" elements in an unordered fashion (I mean you can use `TreeSet` for sorted sets, but that's a different story). A simple workaround would be to make a `List` out of the `Set` and pass it to `Collections.sort`.

Answer (score 5):

Using [GenericComparator.java](http://www.myjeeva.com/2012/04/generic-comparator-in-java/) you will be able to sort following datatypes Integer, String, Long, Double, Float, and Date.

For Ascending order

```
Collections.sort(persons, new GenericComparator("name", true));
```

For Descending order

```
Collections.sort(persons, new GenericComparator("name", false));
```

[Detailed information here!](http://www.myjeeva.com/2012/04/generic-comparator-in-java/)

Comment: Please let me know your reason for down vote. So that I can provide an explanation or improve my answer, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This might work as a basic kick-off example to start with your requirement :

```
// Create a list
String[] strArray = new String[] {"z", "a", "C"};
List list = Arrays.asList(strArray);

// Sort
Collections.sort(list);
// C, a, z

// Case-insensitive sort
Collections.sort(list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
// a, C, z

// Reverse-order sort
Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
// z, a, C

// Case-insensitive reverse-order sort
Collections.sort(list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
Collections.reverse(list);
// z, C, a
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call your comparator by using following code.

```
Collection.sort(myList,new MyComparatorClass());
```

Then you have to create your own comparator class which will perform sorting on your object bean either on ascending or descending order.In that class you can compare the property on which you want to perform sort.Here I perform sorting on the name.

```
public class MyComparator  implements Comparator {

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
      return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my Java 8 generic comparator. You can compare any T on a function f(T) -> R, e.g. Person (T) on birth-date (R). Since f can be a method reference to a getter of T, it's easy to compare on any property (field) of T. It caters for null T's and null R's (you decide whether nulls go first or last), as well as ascending/descending order. Since it uses the *natural ordering* of R, the latter must also implement Comparable. See usage example at end of code.

```
public class CompareUtil {

    public static enum Nulls {FIRST, LAST};
    public static enum Order {ASCENDING, DESCENDING};

    /** Return a Comparator of T on a function f(T) -> R */
    public static <T, R extends Comparable<? super R>> Comparator<T> comparatorOf(
            Function<T, R> function,
            Order order,
            Nulls nulls) {

        Comparator<R> rComparator = Comparator.naturalOrder();

        if (order == Order.DESCENDING) {
            rComparator = rComparator.reversed();
        }
        rComparator = (nulls == Nulls.FIRST)? 
                Comparator.nullsFirst(rComparator) :
                    Comparator.nullsLast(rComparator);

        Comparator<T> tComparator = 
                Comparator.comparing(
                        function, rComparator);

        tComparator = (nulls == Nulls.FIRST)? 
                Comparator.nullsFirst(tComparator) :
                    Comparator.nullsLast(tComparator);

        return tComparator;
    }

//Example: construct a comparator that compares Events on event-date
//in descending date order, putting any nulls at the end of the result set
Comparator<Event> c = comparatorOf(Event::getDate, Order.DESCENDING, Nulls.LAST);
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a `Comparator` interface
like

```
public interface Comparator<T> {
  int compare(T o1, T o2);
  boolean equals(Object obj);
}
```

Write classes which are identified to be compared
for example for date objects

```
public class DateOrderComparator implements Comparator
```

for Rank Comparator

```
public class RankCodeComparator implements Comparator
```

and so on...